# Additional nuget dependency with new sdk-style csproj

Tags: c#, nuget

I used to have nuspec for my library. There I had roslyn analyzers package added using `<dependency/>`. The package is not required for the lib itself. It is needed for the library clients only. Now I use new sdk-style project. The only way to add nuget dependencies there, that I see, is to use `<PackageReference/>`. But that will install the package to the lib itself too. And in my case it breaks the project because analyzers are designed for the clients only. Is there any way to force some package for the clients but avoid for the package. The only option that I see tight now is to use NuspecFile but I want to get rid of nuspec.

Comment: Why does adding the Roslyn Analyzer package to your project break it? If only the clients need the package, why do want to add it as a dependency instead of the client himself, if you do not need it in the first place?

Comment: I want to force the installation because it contains compile-time checks to avoid incorrect usage. For example, if the method is immutable, it won't make sense to call the method without result usages, etc

Answer (score 1):

I do not think, that this is possible with packages references, because it contradicts the concept of dependencies. If your project does not depend on a package, then it is by design not a dependency, especially not if it is only used by clients or it must not be included into your project. It is the **responsibility of the client** to use the package or not.

> I want to force the installation because it contains compile-time checks to avoid incorrect usage.

There is no need for your library to include the package, because there is no dependency. It is an *option* to help avoid incorrect usage. I think that it would be more resonable to let clients choose themselves, whether or not they want to use Roslyn analyzers or not. Keep in mind that there are other analyzers, too, and not everybody might be able to use yours or even want to use yours, but you can recommend it on your project site.

The reason why you can add unused dependencies to NuSpec files is that there is no way for the package manager to know if the package is used anywhere, since there is no build environment or compiler that can check it. It is more of a loophole by design and you may not rely on that.

Comment: No, it is author's responsibility to decide what is optional and what is required. E.g. this is one of the most popular nuget packages https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/main/src/xunit.v3.core/xunit.v3.nuspec#L21. As you can see there analyzers are enforced.

Comment: Do not get me wrong, this is a legitimate case for analyzers. Specifying dependencies in that way just do not seem to be supported with `PackageReference`.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, thanks. Let me upvote the answer to thank you but it is not the right answer. Seems like it is impossible with sdk-style scproj to add such a package